# numpy installation on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, numpy

I have `Python 2.7.9` installed on Windows 7. When I try to install numpy package through `pip` or by downloading `numpy.zip` and running `python setup.py install`, I get various errors containing absence of various libraries. Is it possible to install numpy on Windows for 64-bit Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried these questions/answers?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28947511/3412545

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4554296/3412545

[Installing numpy, matplotlib on windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272338/installing-numpy-matplotlib-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Otherwise, try another distribution link and report back the results here.

**EDIT**: Found good installation notes for posterity including plugin versions for python 2.7.9

https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins